# Error executing INSERT statement via python (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to insert some data into the table called MonitorList. style_code is a string (Examples: 12345, AA12345, CJ91412.)

Here's the code:
`cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO "MonitorList" VALUES (%(style_code)s)''', {'style_code': style_code})`

I'm getting this error:
`Exception: syntax error at or near "bb1111111"`

I tried doing the query manually in pgadmin query editor. Any data that doesn't have letters in it, such as 111111 or 1111-111 gets inserted completely fine. But whenever I try to insert data that has letters in it, such as BB1111111, I get this error:

```
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "MonitorList" VALUES (BB1111111)
                                          ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 35
```

I've already tried specifying the column name in my query like this:

`INSERT INTO "MonitorList" ("StyleCode") VALUES (BB1111111)`

But that didn't fix the problem. The only way that I was able to insert data with letters in it manually is with this query (added single quotes to the data:

`INSERT INTO "MonitorList" ("StyleCode") VALUES ('BB1111111')`

However, adding the single quotes around the `%(style_code)s` in python code doesn't fix the problem.

MonitorList table has just 1 column (Primary key, can't be null, data type: text) Any ideas?

Comment: check datatype of the column in table MonitorList.

Comment: @dassum it's 'text'

Comment: Please share your python code.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with the below code

```
style_code_val = style_code

query =  "INSERT INTO MonitorList (StyleCode) VALUES (%s);"
data = (style_code_val)

cursor.execute(query, data)
```

Comment: just tried, same thing. Anything that doesn't include letters gets inserted fine, but add any letters and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment.

Here is simple test. Check your code in the same way.

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect('')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> a = 'b'
>>> cur.mogrify('select %s', a)
"select 'b'"
>>> cur.mogrify('select %(a)s', {'a': a})
"select 'b'"
>>> type(a) # Note this:
<type 'str'>
```